# Javascript-Get selected option in table

Tags: javascript, html

I've an HTML table and i want to get a selected value in list in a td.

I proceed like this :

```
var table = document.getElementById('ZZ');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            var type =table.rows[r].cells[11].innerHTML;
            alert(type);
        }
    }
```

And i've a result like this in an alert box

```
<SELECT id="" onchange=''... <OPTION value=1>A</OPTION><OPTION selected=2>B</OPTION></SELECT>
```

And i want to get 'B' in a var.
How can i complete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 html:

    <SELECT id="orange" onchange=''... >
       <OPTION value=1>A</OPTION>
       <OPTION selected=2>B</OPTION>
    </SELECT>

    script:

   var allDropdown =  document.getElementsByTagName("select");
   allDropdown[0].value;
  allDropdown[1].value;
```

/**********************************************************/

```
for(var item in allDropdown ){
      alert(allDropdown[item].value)
    }
```

Comment: If i do that i only get one element and i need to do it for all my table.

Comment: var allSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("selectClassName");

Answer (score 4):

Since you say you get the result which you get, you could use [`Element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) which uses css selectors to target the elements.

```
var type = table.rows[r].cells[11].querySelector("[selected]").innerHTML;
```

Note that I'm using innerHTML since there's some variations between `textContent` and `innerText` and also due to the fact that `<option>` cannot contain any html.

Comment: Is telling me "null object or undefined".

Comment: Or Is telling me "The object does not support the property or method "querySelector"".

Answer (score 1):

**

> If your select option exist in the inner child of the td of the table
>   and you wanna get the value, this may help you out. It worked for me

**

```
**HTML**

<table class="table table-borderless" id="all_table_hour">
  <tbody class="table-hours-record">
  <tr data-mytr_id=1 class="table-rowclass1">
    <td>Time</td>
    <td data-mytd1_id=1 class="table-rowtd1class1">
      <div class="time-slot">
        <span >
          <select class="hour_selected_from_all" id="hour_selected_from_all1">    
            <option selected="selected" value="00:00">0 hour</option>
            <option value="01:00">1 hour</option> 
          </select>
        </span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td >
      <div class="time-slot">
        <input placeholder="$10.00">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**

> CODE JS

**

```
var testTable = document.getElementById('all_table_hour');

for (i = 1; i < testTable.rows.length; i++) {

    var recordcells = testTable.rows.item(i).cells;
    for (var j = 0; j < recordcells.length; j++) {
        record = recordcells.item(j).getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value
        //Now you can add this record as per your required format (list or in json format)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
As in your code you are able to get object of TD then you can use "Find" function to find select and take selected option out from the select.
.find("select") will give you select jquery object and then through sudo code used :selected" you can find selected option from list.It will  return you "B".
var table = document.getElementById('ZZ');
for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
 for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
  var type =table.rows[r].cells[11].find("select")**.find(":selected").text()**;
  alert(type);// B
  
 }
}

Hope this will help
```

Comment: Tried and "The object does not support property or "find" method".